# Can my ControllerActionInvoker be a singleton?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, actionresult, controlleractioninvoker

It doesn't seem like `ControllerActionInvoker` has any implementation details that require a new instance to be created for each Controller.  It seems to have two properties with setters that are never used, and getters that are basically lazy references to static members.

I am considering changing the scope of my custom ControllerActionInvoker's life cycle in my ASP.NET MVC application.  Is there a good reason I shouldn't do this?  Is there something I'm missing about this class?

Comment: It's probably fine as long as all your code is thread safe, but I don't really see the point of doing so.

Comment: @Ryan, There's more to it than I put in this question, but this was the only part I was unsure about.

Comment: How did this work out in the end? Ready to answer your own question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything implicitly wrong with implementing the `IActionInvoker` this way.

However, there is also no implicit benefit.  It depends on how you want to scope that particular component of the MVC lifecycle.